# Apache Derby db error ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, derby

I am using Eclipse with WindowsBuilder.   I have created a small simple project to open an existing Derby db and I am getting the following error:-
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
with a call to ClassForName(driver) where driver is "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver".

After googling I made sure that my Windows 7 CLASSPATH includes the following:-
c:\program files\eclipse\plugins\db-derby-10.8.2.2-bin\lib\derby.jar;c:\program files\eclipse\plugins\db-derby-10.8.2.2-bin\lib\derbytools.jar;.

I still have the same problem and I am wondering how to check that the classpath entries above actually point to the driver resource.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: To check that your classpath is pointing at the right thing, try 'java org.apache.derby.tools.ij'. If it gives you a prompt, try "connect 'jdbc:derby:testdb;create=true';". If that doesn't give you any errors, then your classpath is looking good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have You added the derby db .jar file to the projects Java Build Path?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and just added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\db\lib` to the Project properties -> Run/Debug settings -> Classpath -> User entries -> Add External JARs and it works.

No need to:

> Windows 7 CLASSPATH includes the following:- c:\program
>   files\eclipse\plugins\db-derby-10.8.2.2-bin\lib\derby.jar;c:\program
>   files\eclipse\plugins\db-derby-10.8.2.2-bin\lib\derbytools.jar;.